# How to refresh view when key typing on a filter is over, in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a view with a table and a search box above the table. I'm currently refreshing the view everytime a key is released. This causes some lag.

Code:

```
searchText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent ke) {
            filter.setSearchText(searchText.getText());
            viewer.refresh();
        }
        });
```

How can I refresh the view only when the user stops writting ?

Comment: Have you considered using a timer and refreshing when this timer is above a certain threshold ?

Comment: Yes, but how I know the threshold ? I don't want to refresh the view at 1 second every time but just after the user stops pressing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a threshold and [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) :

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(threshold, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    filter.setSearchText(searchText.getText());
    viewer.refresh();
  }
});
timer.setRepeat(false);
searchText.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(final KeyEvent ke) {
        timer.restart();
    }
});
```

Comment: @JohnSmith Did you use javax.swing.timer ?